# Azure website. How to remove default link?

Tags: url, azure, dns, subdomain

I have setup a azure website and uploaded all content etc.

Now I am able to access my website with link `abc.cloudapp.net` which is impacting the SEO of my main domain.

Is there a way where I can block access to my website via `abc.cloudapp.net` and only allow access via `abc.com`?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean *"remove this default link"*? Do you mean you want to use a custom domain name for your site?

Comment: yes, i already added custom domain into it

Comment: If your question isn't clear, it cannot be answered. Please edit to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: But, still i can access my website,  link provided by azure

Comment: By *"link"* do you mean URL?

Comment: yes. when i setup my website. Azure provided me default url ..

Comment: I think what Mohit wants is that nobody should be able to access the website using cloudapp.net domain name and should be accessible via custom domain name only.

Comment: Yes Gaurav . Exactly 

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can turn off access to the website via `[your cloud service name].cloudapp.net` domain.

However what you could do is `include a rewrite rule` in your `web.config`, so that whenever someone tries to access your website via cloudapp.net domain, they are automatically redirected to your custom domain.

From the blog post: http://onthecloud.azurewebsites.net/seo-tip-how-to-block-the-.azurewebsites.net-domain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Disable Azure Domain" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.cloudapp.net" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yourwebsite.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    ...
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[I modified the XML configuration to redirect cloudapp.net; Original post is for Azure Websites]

Another solution is to block access via `cloudapp.net` completely. From this blog post: https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/sspencer/post/2014/12/18/Azure-Websites-Blocking-access-to-the-azurewebsitesnet-url.aspx

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Block traffic to the raw azurewebsites url"  patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*cloudapp.net*" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden"
          statusDescription="Site is not accessible" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```